# How i can communicate from my google chrome extension with another jsp pages?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a google chrome extension that takes the text selected by the user and save in a data base , but the probleme is how i can cummunicate with my servlet(i use JEE) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send data using ajax request from your extension's javascript file to the servlet and then store into database.